# Who is the lowest ranked european team to qualify for world cup?

Tags: football, trivia, ranking, fifa, world-cup

If Iceland wins tonight against Croatia, would they be the lowest ranked team to ever qualify from Europe? 
Also who is the lowest ranking to ever qualify for a world cup from any continent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Oct 2013, Iceland is ranked 46th. Croatia is 18th.

Since, Iceland lost -- and with two games still remaining -- the lowest could either be Jordan (70th) or New Zealand (79th).
However, New Zealand would have to beat Mexico (24th) and Jordan would have to beat Uruguay (6th).

So if Jordan and New Zealand lose their qualifiers, then the lowest ranking European team qualifying in the 2014 world cup will be France (21st) and -- from any continent (bonus) -- Cameroon (59th).

Sources: http://www.fifa.com/worldranking/rankingtable/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification

As for lowest ranking of all time from any continent, El Salvador (80th as of Mar. 2013, 89th as of Nov. 2013) seems to be the answer.

Source: http://www.funtrivia.com/askft/Question130166.html

Comment: If you go by the rankings as of the tournament itself, North Korea are the lowest-ranked side ever to qualify for a World Cup: they were ranked 105th when they qualified for the 2010 World Cup.